# Enable referential integrity with nHIbernate using SQlite database

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, foreign-keys

Good evening everyone,

I've got a project using nHibernate (2.1.2.4000) and System.Data.SQLite (1.0.66.0). I want to enforce NHibernate to create foreign keys when it creates the database or at least use the "foreign key" keyword then I'll be able to create the triggers.

I googled but I didn't find any documentation on how to do that and I'm loosing the faith. I really don't want to (and I won't) check referential integrity inside my code.

In a word: how do I enable referential integrity (or equivalent) with nHibernate and SQLite?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never: here's an answer:

[Foreign Keys with SchemaExport in Fluent NHibernate using SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058005/foreign-keys-with-schemaexport-in-fluent-nhibernate-using-sqlite)

[nHibernate Issue Tracker](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2200)