# enabling SQLite foreignkeys in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, foreign-keys

I've learned that the only way to enable FK constraints in sqlite is to turn on this pragma:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

But unfortunately, if I understood correctly, I will have to execute that query in the beginning of every session. Am I correct?
How can I do it "automatically" with NHibernate? Is there a way to hook into NH and execute that right after opening session?
I'm using NH 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I've found the answer that works for me. Credits goes to James Kovacs ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479901/does-sqlite-coupled-with-nhibernate-support-referential-integrity-foreign-keys))

I've created my own Driver based on SQLite20Driver and overloaded CreateConnection method (code is from [James' GitHub](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/nhibernate/blob/2711450b8fcea66df41699ac595b4cc814d7f64b/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Driver/SQLite20Driver.cs))

```
public override IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        DbConnection connection = (DbConnection)base.CreateConnection();
        connection.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
        return connection;
    }

    private static void Connection_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.OriginalState == ConnectionState.Broken || e.OriginalState == ConnectionState.Closed || e.OriginalState == ConnectionState.Connecting) &&
            e.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            DbConnection connection = (DbConnection)sender;
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                // Activated foreign keys if supported by SQLite.  Unknown pragmas are ignored.
                command.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm :).

Comment: Yes I should, and I will in two days when stackoverflow will allow me :).