# Does Fluent Nhibernate automatically set Foreign Key Contraints on all CreateSQLQuery calls when using SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So I'm attempting to upgrade a SQLite database.  My upgrade requires me to change a column datatype.  Thus my thought processs was to do (I'll call the table `foo`):

1. Create a `foo_temp` table.
2. Insert old data from foo into `foo_temp` table.
3. Drop the old `foo` table.
4. Alter the `foo_temp` table to foo.

However it fails on step 3, because of the foreign key constraints.  I've tried everything from inserting a `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;` before the drop, to appending a `foreign keys=false;` to the connection string.  It doesn't appear Fluent Nhibernate will let me drop this table.  Perhaps there is a setting I can disable when I configure a 'Fluently' connection?  I can't seem to find it.

I've noticed when I go and use a UI client (like SQLiteSpy), it has no problems dropping the table.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

So I've come up with a solution that seems to work.  Using the code I found here (credit goes to ppiotrowicz):

[enabling SQLite foreignkeys in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850331/enabling-sqlite-foreignkeys-in-nhibernate)

I basically swapped out `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` for `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF` and referenced that driver using `SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(cs).Driver<MyDriver>()`